# How do I combine images into a single entity in libgdx?

Tags: java, textures, libgdx, image

I've googled this but can't seem to find anything on "concatenating" two images, especially with libgdx.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you basically want to create another image from two images ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

1. Create a rendertarget
2. Set it to be the target for drawing
3. Draw image one to it.
4. Draw image two to it.
5. Save this render target, holding the combined images.
6. Set the backbuffer as drawing target.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551669/libgdx-spritebatch-render-to-texture) presents the same problem and its solutions should work flawlessly also for your use-case. Just draw your textures with the spritebatch, enabling the framebuffer object created before.

It's easy to Google for details on this...